# Conditionally execute promises in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 2 promises that takes in input 2 differents parameters:

```
promise1(var1)
promise2(var2)
```

These promises runs in parallel inside a Promise.all():

```
Promise.all([promise1(var1), promise2(var2)])
```

Sometimes, depending on the value of var1 or var2, I just need one of them to be executed.
For example, if var1 is null, I just want

```
Promise.all([promise2(var2)])
```

Or, if var2 is null:

```
Promise.all([promise1(var1)])
```

Is there an elegant way to code this situation without if, else branches?

Comment: *I have 2 promises that takes in input 2 differents parameters*.  This is not what you have.  You have two **functions** that return promises and those functions take in different parameters.  You don't execute promises.  You execute functions that return promises. 
 Promises are a notification system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Promise.all([
var1 ? promise1(var1) : Promise.resolve(null),
var2 ? promise2(var2) : Promise.resolve(null),
]);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with dynamically create promise.all array argument.

```
var promises=[];
if(var1==null)
promise.push(promise2(var2));

if(var2==null)
promise.push(promise1(var1));

Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: This won't execute any promise, if both `var1` and `var2`  are different from `null` ...

Comment: what would be the value for those variables if they are not null?

Comment: if you want to exactly check null value it`s ok, but for truly condition just check if they`re truly would be better.

Comment: Thats not my point, but if `var1` and `var2` both have valid values, it should execute `Promise.all(p1(var1), p2(var2)]` and there is no possibility that this can happen in your code ... With your code, this can only happen if `var1` and `var2` are both `null`, which is exaclty the opposite of what OP wants ...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `if .. else` is not elegant? In many situation it's the most readable code and thus IMHO is better than some "well-constructed" oneliner, which you won't understand anymore the next time you are reading it.

I personally would make an array and push the various promises into that array based on the conditions. And then finally make a `Promise.all` with this array. IMO this is the most readable and elegant way to do this.

```
let promises = [];  
if (val1) promises.push(promise1(val1));
if (val2) promises.push(promise1(val2));
Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not go for a solution where *sometimes* you pass an array with 2 promises to `Promise.all`, and *sometimes* just 1. If ever you need to get the resolved values from what `Promise.all` returns, you'll just have a harder time to determine where a value came from. So don't play with the array size. Keep it predetermined.

The better solution would be to adapt the `promise1` and `promise2` function so that they return `null` or `undefined` when the argument they get is `null` (or whatever you want to treat differently). Then call `Promise.all` as you did in your initial code:

```
Promise.all([promise1(var1), promise2(var2)])
```

If you don't want to touch the functions `promise1` and `promise2`, then do:

```
Promise.all([(var1 !== null) && promise1(var1),
             (var2 !== null) && promise1(var2)]);
```

Note that there is no issue when you have a non-promise value in that array. This will be treated as an immediately resolved promise.

Comment: depends on whether you need the results of the promises or not. If they are just `Promise<void>` there is no point in adding a NoOp to the array ...

Comment: Didn't I put that as a condition in my answer? *"...if ever you need to get..."*. It just is good practice. Who knows who will later deal with the code to chain a `.then` to it... That *is* the point -- and it doesn't hurt to do it.